# HAVING clause not working after server update

Tags: mysql, having-clause

We have just made a major upgrade in mysql version from 5.0.51 to 5.6.22 and I have just noticed that one of my queries no longer works properly.

```
SELECT
  p.id AS product_id,
  p.code,
  p.description,
  p.unitofmeasure,
  p.costprice,
  p.packsize,
  vc.rateinpercent,
  CASE
    WHEN Sum(sales.qty) IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE Sum(sales.qty)
  END AS sold,
  CASE
    WHEN stock.stocklevel IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE stock.stocklevel
  END AS stocklevel,
  sum(sales.qty) - stock.stocklevel AS diff,
  CEIL((sum(sales.qty) - stock.stocklevel) / p.packsize) AS amt
FROM   products p
LEFT JOIN 
  ( SELECT 
      col.product_id,
      col.quantity AS qty
    FROM customerorderlines col
    LEFT JOIN customerorders co
    ON co.id = col.customerorder_id
    WHERE co.orderdate >= '2014-12-01 00:00:00'
      AND co.orderdate <= '2015-02-09 23:59:59'
      AND co.location_id IN (1,2,3,7)
  ) sales
  ON sales.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT 
        product_id,
        location_id,
        Sum(stocklevel) AS stocklevel
      FROM stock
      WHERE location_id IN (1,2,3,7)
      GROUP BY product_id
    ) stock
  ON stock.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN vatcodes vc 
  ON vc.id = p.purchasevatcode_id
WHERE p.supplier_id IN (137)
  AND p.currentstatus_v = 1
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING sold > stocklevel
ORDER BY sold DESC
```

On the old server, the HAVING clause filtered out all results with minuses in, giving a result as follows:

[image: Old Result]

Instead, I am getting the following result on the new server:

[image: New Result]

Basically, it's filtering out *some* of the negative results but not all of them. (The datasets are a few days old, which is why the 'Freeze Gel Spray' qty and sold and stock numbers are slightly different)

Hindsight is a wonderful thing but I didn't expect there to by any major changes for queries between server updates so I didn't care to test or check anything. Luckily this one of only two or three queries that use HAVING, so if I have to re-write a couple of queries so be it. Any ideas as to why this is though? If it wasn't working at all, fair enough, but to only be working partially?

Thanks in advance for any insight,

R

Answer (score 1):

I take it you've tried EXPLAIN on the query to find out what it's doing?

Try making the calculated field names unique from the underlying field names so you can be sure what you're filtering on. I've seen some screwy results when the calculated fields have the same names as underlying physical fields.

Having your subqueries return the same format of results (i.e. both summed/grouped) helps to see what's going on.

I haven't tested this query but it may help. If you post the table structures and perhaps some fake data that shows the error, that would help diagnose

```
SELECT 
    p.id AS product_id,
    p.code,
    p.description,
    p.unitofmeasure,
    p.costprice,
    p.packsize,
    vc.rateinpercent,
    sales.totalSold,
    stock.totalStock,
    sales.totalSold - stock.totalStock AS diff,
    CEIL((sales.totalSold - stock.totalStock) / p.packsize) AS amt
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        col.product_id,
        IFNULL( SUM(col.quantity), 0) AS totalSold
    FROM    customerorderlines col
    LEFT JOIN customerorders co
    ON      co.id = col.customerorder_id
    WHERE   co.orderdate >= '2014-12-01 00:00:00'
    AND     co.orderdate <= '2015-02-09 23:59:59'
    AND     co.location_id IN (1,2,3,7)
    GROUP   BY product_id
) sales
ON  sales.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        product_id,
        IFNULL( SUM(stocklevel), 0) AS totalStock
    FROM    stock
    WHERE   location_id IN (1,2,3,7)
    GROUP   BY product_id
) stock
ON  stock.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN vatcodes vc
ON  vc.id = p.purchasevatcode_id
WHERE   p.supplier_id IN (137)
AND     p.currentstatus_v = 1
GROUP   BY p.id
HAVING  totalSold > totalStock
ORDER   BY totalSold DESC
```